# How can we view the error logs which caused "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated."

Tags: android-studio

2022-05-05 07:44:41,561 [3360158]   INFO - WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Windows Defender status: UNKNOWN_STATUS; projectDirExcluded? false
2022-05-05 07:44:41,594 [3360191]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 949 ms
2022-05-05 07:44:41,594 [3360191]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models.
2022-05-05 07:44:41,594 [3360191]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = true
2022-05-05 07:44:43,200 [3361797]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
2022-05-05 07:44:43,219 [3361816]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,219 [3361816]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | Could not find GLES 2.x config!
2022-05-05 07:44:43,219 [3361816]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
2022-05-05 07:44:43,219 [3361816]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
2022-05-05 07:44:43,219 [3361816]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,235 [3361832]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
2022-05-05 07:44:43,266 [3361863]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
2022-05-05 07:44:43,266 [3361863]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,652 [3362249]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected
2022-05-05 07:44:43,685 [3362282]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
2022-05-05 07:44:43,685 [3362282]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_4740.ini
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,746 [3362343]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ERROR   | crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: 3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
2022-05-05 07:44:43,761 [3362358]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:
2022-05-05 07:44:45,156 [3363753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
2022-05-05 07:44:45,156 [3363753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2022-05-05 07:44:45,156 [3363753]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
2022-05-05 07:44:45,326 [3363923]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopAll()
2022-05-05 07:44:45,381 [3363978]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
2022-05-05 07:44:52,171 [3370768]   INFO - s.MemorySettingsRecommendation - recommendation based on machine: 1280, on project: 1280

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I have faced and resolved:

- Step 1: C:\Users\Prashant Kumar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk delete all
  file
- Step 2:Update SDK manager in SDK platform and SDK tools
- Step 3: Again we will install the emulator with the updated package
  then the issue won't come.

now I am able to run the emulator using CMD.